# Apache Proxy and Alias combined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a webserver (Debian, Apache, MySQL) set up and I'm still using the default configuration as it came with the installation.
I also installed phpMyAdmin which is linked to example.com/phpmyadmin with an alias.
And now my problem: I want to set up a Rails application with Phusion Passenger (standalone) which I want to reach at example.com/railsapp. Therefore I need to tell Apache to proxy all requests to that address to localhost:3000 (which is where Passenger provides the rails app).
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your vhost config:

```
ProxyPassMatch /railsapp(.*) http://localhost:3000/$1
ProxyPassReverse /railsapp http://localhost:3000
```